# FMCW Range-doppler map

Tags: radar

I am trying to form a range-doppler map using dechirped signals. I wanted know if there are any resources that provide and explain the steps taken to form the range-doppler map.
If there are or you could provide a simple flowchart to form the range-doppler map that would be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: May I interest you in this answer? https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/68368/26009

Comment: That helps, but i was also looking for the analytical development of the dechirpped signal in terms of fourier transform

Comment: For a single pulse, the de-chirped single is a single sinusoid that has a frequency that directly depends on the range of the target. The post I linked shows how that time-domain signal is derived. Since the signal after de-chirping is a sinusoid, the Fourier transform of it is a delta at the frequency of interest. Now, if you want a complete description of how the range-Doppler map is formed analytically, that is a different story. However, my post shows how to form it from scratch, in which you should be able to determine what you need with a little work.

Comment: @Envidia If the quadratic phase term is ignored/negligible then this is correct. In some systems it is not negligible and needs to be compensated. I also commented on you linked answer.

Comment: @Envidia Thank you I was able to work it out